# Where can I find flight manuals (not familiarization manuals) from Project Gemini?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, nasa, project-gemini

I have heard about the Project Gemini flight manuals, but have not been able to locate a copy. Perhaps someone here knows if these exist in some form?
I am NOT talking about the Familiarization manual, which is often called the flight manual, I have this data already.

I am also very interested in other sources of detailed info on the use of the cockpit instrumentation, and especially the flight procedures involving the actual operation of the spacecraft... I have some Flight Plans, but need more background information on WHY and WHAT many of the steps are actually doing. I am interested in building a Gemini flight simulator, if it helps show the kind of info I am after.

Comment: This collection claims to contain flight manuals: https://www.thehistoricalarchive.com/products/c665.html. Some of those documents used to be available online but are not any longer.

Comment: @called2voyage hmm, its only mentioned in the overview, there's nothing that looks like the actual manuals in the listed titles :/

Comment: Yeah, I was dissatisfied with the list myself, but it was the best I could find.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer on 2ndary question on cockpit instrumentation, like the programming manual for the onboard computers. See https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/links.html#Gemini_spacecraft_computer The site also has source code for computer simulator. (more comment level answer, but don't have the rep).

Answer (score 2):

The Gemini Program manuals are not searchable via the NASA JSC History or Archive databases, but are currently housed in the National Archives and Records Administration, Fort Worth Regional Archive. The accession number is A-20-64-3. To access these documents, contact the Fort Worth Facility.

Comment: I contacted them. No reply. I'm not sure this answer deserves the bounty, since I didnt actually get any answer at all, but I appreciate the effort, thanks.